# How can screenshots/video taken from a 3DS XL be uploaded to a computer?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I see people uploading videos and images of 3DS games all the time.  I also see Twitch and Youtube videos of people showing off their top and sometimes even their bottom screens to the viewers.

How does someone record or stream their top and/or bottom screens?
If screenshots are taken on the 3DS, how are they uploaded to a computer (USB charger?)? 
Are special cords or accessories needed to do this?

Comment: What you're asking now isn't really gaming related; uploading to Youtube or another site is general computer usage.  If you're not using the 3DS's capabilities, it's not a gaming problem, I feel.

Comment: Fair enough.  Is there a SE that would be better suited or should I go to Gamefaqs or something?

Comment: Take a look at the second comment on the dupe answer; it's...kinda sorta possible, but you'll need to crack open your 3DS to do what most streamers are doing, I think.  Unfortunately, I don't believe there's an official supported method to get high quality video from the 3DS anywhere else.